# Relation between blood type and personality

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would name the belief that your personality is related to your blood type.

Comment: Yes, I've heard about diets being tailored to people's blood groups. And each blood group has certain personality characteristics. Once upon a time it used to be called *astrology*... I am not terribly convinced by the science that lies behind this revolutionary approach.

Comment: I would say that the belief is "*bloody ridiculous*".

Comment: It's discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_types_in_Japanese_culture, but I don't see a name for it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Astrology is the pseudo-science that postulates that heavenly bodies -- planets and stars in their configuration in constellations -- determine human characteristics and the outcome of  human affairs.  I don't think blood type enters into it.  Astrologic nonsense is much older than the discovery of blood types.

Comment: There is not much difference between this and the "humors" postulated by Greek philosophers.

Comment: If this is primarily a Japanese phenomenon, it might be better just to use the Japanese word for it.

Comment: I don't know about name, but "delusional" seems to be the most accurate word to describe such a belief. Not every single imagined pseudo-scientific nonsensical correlation is deserving of a unique name.

Comment: @deadrat Give me some credit for knowing that the discovery of blood groups is in its infancy compared to astrology.  The comment was pointing out that personality traits linked to blood groups, is as absurd as the belief that planets determine our personalities and future.This blood group business/science/fad is the 2000-2015 equivalent of the crystal phenomena that was so popular back in the 1980s and 1990s. Neverthrless there are some very strong supporters (in Italy) of a dietary regime based on one's blood group.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry for not giving you enough credit.  What's the antecedent to "it" in your comment again?  And what's "once upon a time"?  Astrology is still with us, going strong.  Even when you're sure the receiver is faulty, it's a good thing to check the transmitter.

Comment: @deadrat that's very funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly, the closest thing to a singular term that I can find would probably be "**Blood Type Anthropology**" or "**Blood Type Humanics**" - the former seems to be the more exact translation of the term that Masahiko Nomi [created to describe it](http://human-abo.org), and the latter a more casual way of referring to it, with even his son's center referred to as the "Institute of Blood Type Humanics".  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find much of a better English source; if you'd prefer to have more, I can certainly try to find something.

Comment: Thank you! Along with @James 's comment and wikipedia link, these provide a complete answer. Although I was asking for an English equivalent to something that seemingly is only found in Japanese culture (didn't know that!), I am happy to have found a way to call these expressions in English! 
I wish your answer and James' comment could be merged somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [sanguine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sanguine):

(Archaic)

> - Having blood as the dominant humor in terms of medieval physiology.
> - Having the temperament and ruddy complexion formerly thought to be characteristic of a person dominated by this humor; passionate.

American Heritage Dictionary

If you are referring to the following [issue](http://www.quora.com/Does-blood-type-affect-human-behaviour), it appears that there is no single word for it, and you just should use an expression such as: *behaviour related to blood type*:

> - In some nations -- for example, Japan -- many people believe that  blood type affects personality and vocational success, and people considering  marriage might seek to determine compatibility based on blood type (Sabo &  Watanabe, 1992; Sullivan, 1995/2000).
> - In that sense, blood type seems to perform  a similar function that astrological belief in the power of the Zodiac plays in  the West, except that in Japan such views are taken much more seriously;  according to Sullivan, "Japan has an obsession with blood types."
> - In the United  States, naturopathic medicine often places great store on blood type, and a  recent popular treatment of the subject (D'Adamo & Whitney, 1996) described  differences between individuals with different blood types in sweeping terms  that included vocational differences.
> - Although at first glance the claims that  blood type affects. 
>     vocational behavior may seem absurd, certainly many Japanese  and some Americans believe it does, and the empirical evidence (especially the  more recent evidence) is sufficiently mixed to give a skeptic pause.

(www.quora.com)

Comment: No, I really meant blood group. As in "this is a typical reaction from a blood type B person like you".

Comment: @fabriced Are you confusing the Type A/Type B personality types with blood groups?